# inter- and intra- prefix

Tags: words, english-to-japanese, prefixes

What would one use for the equivalent of the "inter-" and "intra-" prefixes in English?

e.g. intercity, intracity, inter-server etc

I did a fair amount of looking around. 間 looks like it might be usable for some of the inter- words and 内 for a fare few of the intra- (intramural soccer = 校内サッカーリーグor学内サッカーリーグ？）but I was hoping there would be something more consistent.

Comment: My guess is: because you didn't show much of an attempt to figure out the answer yourself. Look up intercity, interstate, interregion, intracity, intraregion etc in a dictionary and see if you notice any patterns.

Comment: `外` vs `内`. Here you go.

Comment: oldergod > 外 means outside, not inter-, 内 means inside not intra-

Comment: dainichi > I actually did do a fair amount of looking stuff up but found nothing consistent. Even if it were the case that I didn't do research, why would that mean that this should be labeled as "off topic". It's certainly not off-topic

Comment: @paullb for intra-, click http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intra- , scroll down to "World English Dictionary" where it says "inside"... For inter-, I agree that 外 is the wrong translation. 間 works better.

Comment: Sorry if I gave the wrong impression, I didn't vote to close, I'm just guessing. As for 間 and 内, I'd say you're pretty much on the spot. If you're worried about consistency, maybe list some words that you feel dont fit the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate inter- and intra- to ～間 and ～内 respectively.

(Note that they become suffixes rather than prefixes in Japanese.)

References:

- I read [dainichi's comments](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/inter-and-intra-prefix#comment19819_9428) above;
- I found [this answer](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1172462851) on ye olde Bag o' Wisdom;
- I looked for patterns in the inter- and intra- words in my Kenkyusha J-E dictionary; and
- I briefly checked Google to see if the patterns seemed correct.