# Usage of 内 for inside / within something

Tags: grammar, kanji

In my vocabulary learning I've recently come across the pattern of 社内、車内、体内　and was wondering... can I apply this pattern of [something]内 to many other things?

For example, if I wanted to say "in the　station" could I say 駅内？

How about "in the team", would it be valid to say "チーム内" or is it just for places you can physically enter?

It's a hard one to Google because of how they just break it down to ない。

Comment: Partly related, maybe? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9428/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35981/9831

Comment: We also have 国内、県内、都内、府内、市内、区内、町内、室内、場内、会場内、構内、船内、電車内、列車内、機内、空港内、店内、邸内、党内、部内、組織内、屋内、庫内、館内、学内、大学内、城内、圏内、胎内、区域内、管内、範囲内、～地内、～域内、～構内、～場内, etc...

Comment: Thanks @Chocolate. Partially related, extremely useful and much appreciated. And thanks for the list of other examples. The fun never ends!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 駅｛えき｝ ⇒ (No) 駅内 ⇒ (Yes) 駅{えき}構内｛こうない｝ *station premises*, *station yard*, (Yes) 駅[中]{なか}
  駅弁{えきべん}は、「**駅構内**で販売｛はんばい｝される弁当｛べんとう｝」を意味｛いみ｝する。*Ekiben means "a box lunch sold within station premises"*.
  **駅中** is a newly coined word, which is a common name for commercial space developed in railway stations located under jurisdiction by Japanese railway operators, and it is explained [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A7%85%E3%83%8A%E3%82%AB).
  It is written as 駅ナカ, エキナカ or 駅中 etc.
- チーム ⇒ (Yes) チーム[内]{ない}
- 仲間{なかま} *members of one's group* ⇒ (Yes) 仲間[内]{うち}
  **仲間内**の約束｛やくそく｝ごと *conventions of the buddy*
- 学校{がっこう} ⇒ (?) 学校内 ⇒ (Yes) 校内｛こうない｝, (Yes) 学校[中]｛じゅう｝
  **校内**[放送]{ほうそう} *school public address system*; *broadcasts aired within the school*
  彼{かれ}は学校/**学校中**で一番｛いちばん｝背｛せ｝が高｛たか｝い。 *He is the tallest student in my school.*
- 家庭{かてい} *family* ⇒ (Yes) 家庭[内]{ない}
  **家庭内**[暴力]{ぼうりょく} *domestic violence*
- 病院｛びょういん｝ *hospital* ⇒ (Yes) 病院[内]{ない}, (Yes) 院内｛いんない｝, (Yes) 病院[中]{じゅう}, (No) 院中
  **病院内**/**院内**では静粛｛せいしゅく｝にお願｛ねが｝いします。 *Please be quiet in the hospital!*
  **院内**[感染]{かんせん} *healthcare-acquired infection [HAI]*; *nosocomial infection*
  Ａ先生{せんせい}が看護婦｛かんごふ｝のＢさんを好｛す｝きなのは**病院中**の誰｛だれ｝もが知｛し｝っている。 *Everyone knows that doctor A is into nurse B in the hospital.*
  あの火事｛かじ｝では、あっという間｛ま｝に煙｛けむり｝が**病院中**に広｛ひろ｝がった。 *At that fire, smoke quickly spread within the building of the hospital.*

Comment: Thanks for that. So it looks as though, like with much in Japanese, there isn't a definite set logic to follow and things generally better to learn these instances on an individual basis.

Comment: If anything I'd assume the converse -- If a compound word contains the Kanji 内 it likely has to do with something within something else, but not necessarily all expressions that have to do with something within something else will use the Kanji 内 (some may use the Kanji 中 or something else).